# Postgresql Vacuum blocked, I want ignore some tables

Tags: database, postgresql, locking, psql, vacuum

I automatically run a script that performs a FULL VACUUM on my Posrtgresql databases but today it crashed because the process was blocked (surely by another operation on the table).

I want to make sure that he ignores the tables on which there is already a lock, how to do?

Thank you

Comment: `VACUUM (FULL)` normally doesn't crash if encounters a lock, so maybe you should explain that in more detail. Are you sure you need `VACUUM (FULL)` regularly?

Comment: Yes, once a week. I do :
`acuum FULL VERBOSE ANALYZE;
reindex database postgres;`